# Send email automatically

Tags: php, html, forms, email

How can I send an already prepared email automatically to an email adress entered into a text field created from html?  And I should get back a confirmation mail that the user has opened the link sent through that mail.
I want to do it with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements for your little mail project are not very specific. So all we can offer you is to have a look at html forms. You can process them with phps POST-method and that way send a mail through phps [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. After processing you can easily send another mail at the same time to you so you get notified when something happens!

Good luck!